# how to add multiple g:select

Tags: javascript, grails

http://www.4shared.com/download/8Q8J5E2Z/122.PNG?tsid=20130924-025921-5796ea2b

when a click button "ADD", below combobox User will append a combobox again...with javascript..

i don't know how to do it..when i tried with jQuery last night..but it cannot be append...

```
<g:select name="user.id" from="${userdetailsList?.firstName}" noSelection="['':'User']"/>


<html>
    <head>
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'CurrencyList.label', default: 'CurrencyList')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>          
    </head>
    <body>  
    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div id="userMessage" class="info" style="color:orange;background-color:#d0e4fe;">${flash.message}</div>
    </g:if>
    <table align="left">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:20px;" colspan="3"><b>Group Add</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="70">Name</td>
            <td width="5">:</td>
            <td><g:textField name="namagrup" value="${nama}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><g:textArea name="deskripsigrup" value="myValue" rows="5" cols="40"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>

    </tbody>    
</table>
        <ol>
        <h3 >User</h3>
        <br>
        <div id="selects"><g:select name="user.id" 
                    from="${userdetailsList?.firstName}"  
                    noSelection="['':'User']" /> </div>
        <button>ADD</button>  
        <br>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The purpose of g:select is to run on the server-side to generate a `<select>` tag.  Unless you want to render a template from a server-side controller action, you cannot render a "`g:select`" with javascript.  Do you need to help with jQuery to create a second `<select>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to make an Ajax call to the controller and in that method return the g.select with all the options.

Something similar to the following should work...

Add in your 'Add' button a call to a function in the onclick attribute, and inside this function add...

```
$.ajax({
   url: "${createLink(action:'loadSelect')}",
   success: function(data, status){
       $("#selects").append(data);
   }
})
```

Also create a div with id 'selects' so the selects can be appended there.

```
<div id="selects"></div>
```

And in your controller add...

```
def loadSelect(){
    // whatever you need to get the data...
    render "<g:select name='user.id' from='${userdetailsList?.firstName}' noSelection='[\'\':\'User\']'/>"
}
```

Haven't tested it, so try it and tell me if you need more help

Edit: Answer to your code
If I have understood right, you just need to 'clone' the select to be able to add several users to a group. In this case you don't need to go again to the controller and database to generate a new select.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'CurrencyList.label', default: 'CurrencyList')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.list.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function addSelect(){
                 $("#selects").append($("#firstSelect").clone());
            }
        </script>        
    </head>
    <body>  
    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div id="userMessage" class="info" style="color:orange;background-color:#d0e4fe;">${flash.message}</div>
    </g:if>
    <table align="left">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:20px;" colspan="3"><b>Group Add</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="70">Name</td>
            <td width="5">:</td>
            <td><g:textField name="namagrup" value="${nama}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><g:textArea name="deskripsigrup" value="myValue" rows="5" cols="40"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>

    </tbody>    
</table>
        <ol>
        <h3 >User</h3>
        <br>
        <div id="selects"><g:select id="firstSelect" name="user.id" 
                    from="${userdetailsList?.firstName}"  
                    noSelection="['':'User']" /> </div>
        <button onclick="addSelect()">ADD</button>  
        <br>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show me the example coding?i'm seriously blank with that

Comment: sorry, i really confuse...i already edit my post...there're my coding...i never use ajax

Comment: you don't want to use ajax or you just haven't used it before? Also, the select will be always the same or something can change between Add button clicks?

Comment: oh...i havenot used it before ...actually,the select value is from database, and when i click "ADD", it will append below the combobox and it can delete the combobox(the select)

Comment: see updated answer, if I've understood now right it should give you what you want...

Comment: sorry, when i press "ADD"..it will be clone...after clone..can i delete that clone?

Comment: and when click ADD, that clone at beside the select, can i place it below the select..so like vertical...

Comment: The position of the selects it's just matter of styles, maybe try to set it's width to 100% (don't know if the div or the selects, I am not very good with styles...)
And to be able to delete them, you should add another button or something that when clicked will delete the select and the delete button. It's better if you try it first on your own to learn. Should be just to create that button, add a javascript function associated and delete there the element. I think it can be easier if you incluide the select and the delete button inside a div...

Comment: so...to delete the select,must use function again?if to add is "append", how about delete?