# Removing last cloned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972264/how-to-add-multiple-gselect), I am trying to be able to add and remove select boxes for different parts of my document. However, when I call the remove function, it removes the first instance of my cloned object, instead of the last. I have tried using :last and :last-child, but they do not seem to be working(May just be a syntax error, as I am new to Javascript/Jquery)

Also, should I be assigning different id's to each of my cloned objects? My goal is for each g:select to select a database object,  and compile all of the different objects text into 1 big string (each object has a 'documentBody' field that I want to compile). Since I am basically doing the same thing to each object, is it necessary for me to assign specific id's to each select, or will just cloning them be sufficient?

Here is what I currently have implemented

```
        <div id="selects">
        <g:select name="intro" 
        id= "intro" from="${package.name.Subtag.findAllWhere(tag: package.name.Tag.get(2))}" noSelection="['': 'Please choose Subtag']"/>
        </div>

        <button onclick="addSelect()">Add</button> 
        <button onclick="removeSelect(intro)">Remove</button>
```

and

```
    <g:javascript library="jquery"/>
    <g:javascript>
            function addSelect(){
            var cloner = $("#intro").clone();
             $("#selects").append(cloner);

        }
            function removeSelect(id){
                $("#intro:last-child").remove();

        }

    </g:javascript>
```

Comment: thats invalid, id duplicacy is there. IDs should be unique per elem in a single page.

Comment: You could change the ID of each new clone but it's just much cleaner and trouble-free to use class selectors instead.

Comment: You can use the last() method provided by jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After switching to class selectors, the .last() method worked successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai) has mentioned, the issue is that you are cloning and appending an element with an id, creating a duplicate id on the page.  When jQuery searches for an element by id, it stops at the first one found, regardless of any other pseudo classes.

The issue is that a duplicate id on the page means that the HTML document is invalid, so all bets are off.  Older browsers may even throw an error.  Using a class rather than an id prevents the `.clone()` function from copying the dupe id, but if you still need the first element's id, you can always remove it from your cloned object before appending it to the page:

`cloner.removeAttr('id');`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I switched to classes rather than ids, but at the suggestion of someone else, I organized it by tags rather than classes. For example, to remove, I now have `$("select[tag=" + tagName + " ]").last().remove();`, each tag is associated with a particular g:select config. I am now using the class attribute to group all my selects into 1 class, and later on I obtain the values for all selects contained in that class. Is there a preferred way of grouping these (e.g. switching my tag and class use), or does it not really matter